# How to handle authentication electron.js

Tags: angular, electron

I am working on a desktop app with electron.js. I have angular install in it to make single page application. Now i want to have a user login and registration i.e basic authentication system. 
But the problem is how do I handle if the user is logged in.  Where do I store user token and which will be available throughout the application and can also be available in the HTML pages so that I can do conditional rendering using `ng-if`

This is my first time working with JS framework,so I am not really sure on what to look for.
Please help.

Comment: There are lots of available tutorials regarding different strategies for this

Comment: If you're writing an Electron app that connects a remote server, the authentication would be handled on the remote server.  If your application is running locally, why is the existing OS level authentication that occurs insufficient?  It seems like any authentication you put into the Electron app itself will be insecure.

Comment: @mpr I am using firebase authentication for authenticating users. So i m thinking of storing user UID and basic information somewhere which can be accessable from anywhere in the application even from the HTML views. Like in PHP and others.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite for electron/nodejs package that you can import and use. and if you want variables to be accessible in renderer process that can be done using electron IPC. or html storage can be used.

Comment: I am using firebase authentication for authenticating users